# How to add column A (date column) to Column B ( number of business days) in teradata to get the new date?

Tags: loops, date, teradata, procedure

Here's my data;

table A.pickup_date is a date column

table A.biz_days is the business days I want to add up to A.pickup_date

table B.date

table B.is_weekend (Y or N)

table B. is_holiday (Y or N)

Basically from table B, I know for each date, if any date is a business day or not. Now I want to have a third column in table A for the exact date after I add A.business_days to A.pickup_date.

Can anyone provide me with either a case when statement or procedure statement for this? Unfortunately we are not allowed to write our own functions in Teradata.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have sample code to show us where you are stuck?

Comment: I just don't know how to write a loop here maybe within a procedure to implement the python logic as  def date_by_adding_business_days(from_date, add_days):
    business_days_to_add = add_days
    current_date = from_date
    while business_days_to_add > 0:
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        weekday = current_date.weekday()
        if weekday >= 5: # sunday = 6
            continue
        business_days_to_add -= 1
    return current_date

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty darned ugly, but I think it should get you started.

First I created a volatile table to represent your table a:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt_pickup AS
(SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS pickup_date,
8 AS Biz_Days) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(pickup_date)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt_pickup VALUES ('2015-02-24',5);
```

Then I joined that with sys_calendar.calendar to get the days of the week:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_Days AS 
(
SELECT
            p.pickup_date,
            day_of_week
            FROM

            vt_pickup p
            INNER JOIN sys_calendar.CALENDAR c
            ON c.calendar_date >= p.pickup_date 
            AND c.calendar_date < (p.pickup_date + Biz_Days)
) WITH DATA 
PRIMARY INDEX(pickup_date)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

Then I can use all that to generate the actual delivery date:

```
SELECT 
p.pickup_date,
p.biz_days,
biz_days + COUNT(sundays.day_of_week) + COUNT (saturdays.day_of_week) AS TotalDays,
COUNT (sundays.day_of_week) AS Suns,
COUNT (saturdays.day_of_week) AS Sats,
p.pickup_date + totaldays AS Delivery_Date,
FROM 
    vt_pickup p
    LEFT JOIN vt_days AS Sundays ON
         p.pickup_date = sundays.pickup_date
         AND sundays.day_of_week = 1
        LEFT JOIN vt_days AS saturdays ON
            p.pickup_date = saturdays.pickup_date
            AND saturdays.day_of_week = 7
GROUP BY 1,2
```

You should be able to use the logic with another alias for your holidays.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I get your logic. But I think this won't work accurately because what if "COUNT(sundays.day_of_week) + COUNT (saturdays.day_of_week)" is a fairly large number, say, 10? Then I still need to exclude those non-biz days in 10, it seems like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is calculating a sequential number of business days (add it as a new column to your calendar table if it's a recurring operation, otherwise using WITH):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN is_weekend = 'Y' OR is_holiday = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS biz_day#
```

Then you need two joins:

```
SELECT ..., c2.calendar_date 
FROM tableA AS a 
JOIN tableB AS c1
  ON a.pickup_date = c1.calendar_date
JOIN tableB AS c2
  ON c2.biz_day# = c1.biz_day# + a.biz_days 
 AND is_weekend = 'N'
 AND is_holiday = 'N'
```